# How to move an object towards a direction without stopping

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I'm developing a small game in Swift 3 with SpriteKit and I want to move the enemies to the direction of the character, but at all times the enemies stop when they arrive at the character's initial position.

I'm doing this:

```
enemigo.name = "enemigo"
enemigo.position = CGPoint(x: 280, y: 100)
enemigo.xScale = 1/1
enemigo.yScale = 1/15
addChild(enemigo)


let movement1 = CGVector(
    dx: (enemigo.position.x - personaje.position.x)*10,
    dy: (enemigo.position.y - personaje.position.y)*10
)

let actionTransaction = SKAction.move(by: movement1, duration: 20)
enemigo.run(actionTransaction)
```

How should I move the enemies to a specific direction without stopping at the initial position of the character?

Comment: basically you want the enemy to chase the player?

Comment: I want to move enemy towards my character's direction without stopping @Fluidity

Comment: Ok. You will need to update the enemy's action in your scene's `.update()` method. Otherwise your bad guy only gets one movement... he needs more!

Also, here is a great article on doing the proper maths for it:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/90520/trigonometry-games-sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Ok, thanks! @Fluidity

Comment: @Fluidity It is not that performant nor needed to run SKAction inside an update method. That method is executed 60 times per second. If you use it, then you change position property of a node directly. LIke this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36235426/3402095

Comment: I agree with Whirlwind, why you must use actions inside an update method  if you have `zRotation` and `position` references

Answer (score 2):

You've done all the hard work figuring out the vector of direction.

Now you can repeat this [**moveBy action**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417739-move) as often as you like, and the enemy will keep moving in the same direction, further and further, because `move(by: CGVector)` is relative, not absolute:

```
let actionTransaction = SKAction.move(by: movement1, duration: 20)
```

So all you need do is run this forever [**with a key**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483042-run), so you can then seek it out from anywhere, and stop it whenever you like.

```
run(SKAction.repeatForever(actionTransaction), withKey: "movingEnemy")
```

Comment: I have the `let actionTransaction = SKAction.move(by: movement1, duration: 20)` in a function and I call this function in the `sceneDidLoad()`, and it didn't run as what I want. How I should use the `run(SKAction.repeatForever(actionTransaction), withKey: "movingEnemy")`?  @Confused

Comment: I think you read the question a tad bit too literally Confused :P

Comment: @HessianMad I don't think any of us still quite understand what you are trying to do. Could you please elaborate? O, me explica en español :), y voy a intentar entenderlo

Comment: @HessianMad you say the same thing 3 times. that you want to keep  enemies moving. since thats not what you want, draw a picture of what you do want.

Comment: @Fluidity, yeah... I should have posted this as a comment... ;)

Comment: @Fluidity lo que quiero es que el enemigo vaya en dirección a la del jugador sin pararse, es decir, que vaya hacía la dirección del jugador y se salga de la pantalla del juego. ¿Me explico?

Comment: @HessianMad truly, try to draw a diagram. This is something that has multiple possible objectives, and nobody can be sure until you show what you want. I've hit google translate with your Spanish, and it's saying that my answer is what you want. Run it on the enemigo. See if it does what you want. And reduce the duration to something reasonable, like 2 seconds. So it doesn't take 20 seconds to see if it does what you want.

Comment: @HessianMad Ok, so you *do* want the enemy to leave the game screen, yes? You don't want the enemy to follow the player... no seguir el jugador... Yes? So, solo uno movimiento del enemigo.. only one enemy movement... towards the player, then off the screen. IF so, Confused's answer should work, since you already have the correct math

Comment: you could also try using `physicsBody` and `applyImpulse`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could consider using GameplayKit together with SpriteKit. GameplayKit provides standard implementations of common algorithms for games and can be used together with SpriteKit.

Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with it, so I can't give you code. I would suggest having a look at Apple's GameplayKit programming guide. There are functions available for setting a goal of an agent (e.g. an enemy) to move toward a specific location, avoid obstacles, intercept another agent, or flee from an agent, etc.

So while your player moves, some enemies could be programmed to try and catch the player, while other enemies could try to run away from the player. Other enemies could be made to wander around randomly, etc.

So in a nutshell, GameplayKit can add quite powerful functionality to a SpriteKit game. This could mean spending a bit more time upfront thinking about the architecture of your game, but in the end it could be worth it if you will also use the other functionalities of GameplayKit.